# Ubuntu Can't connect bluetooth devices and persistent pairing popup (input-hog profile accept failed)

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, keyboard

I was away for a week from home and when I came back, I could not connect my wireless keyboard (Akko 3068B Plus) to my Dell Vostro laptop on Ubuntu Jammy. My mouse and wireless earphones were working fine.

This is the error I was getting from systemctl/journalctl: `src/service.c:service_accept() input-hog profile accept failed for F4:EE:25:E9:D1:58`

Here are the steps I took:

1. Reinstalled bluez (after resetting, all other peripherals can't connect, mouse, earphones)
2. Tried unpair/untrust/disconnect/remove and vice versa from bluetoothctl
3. Software update/upgrade
4. Cold and hard restart
5. Factory reset the keyboard

PS. Tried pairing the keyboard with a Windows machine, works fine. When I tried re-pairing my mouse, it connects but every few seconds I would get a popup that says `"Bluetooth4.0Mouse wants to pair with this device.Do you want to allow pairing?`

I'm getting really frustrated as I can't do my work and all my macros are in the keyboard, it's getting uncomfortable using the navigator and laptop keyboard. Thanks for anyone who could help.